# Pyspark grouping and structuring data

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have the following data in spark 2.4.5:

```
data = [
    ('1234', '203957', '2010', 'London', 'CHEM'),
    ('1234', '203957', '2010', 'London', 'BIOL'),
    ('1234', '288400', '2012', 'Berlin', 'MATH'),
    ('1234', '288400', '2012', 'Berlin', 'CHEM'),
]
d = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['auid', 'eid', 'year', 'city', 'subject'])
d.show()

+----+------+----+------+-------+
|auid|   eid|year|  city|subject|
+----+------+----+------+-------+
|1234|203957|2010|London|   CHEM|
|1234|203957|2010|London|   BIOL|
|1234|288400|2012|Berlin|   MATH|
|1234|288400|2012|Berlin|   CHEM|
+----+------+----+------+-------+
```

from which I need to get df grouped by `auid`, with a chronological order of cities, i.e. `London, Berlin` and `[[Berlin, 2010], [London, 2012]]` in another column, plus I need sorted by descending frequency column with subjects: `[CHEM,2], [BIOL, 1], [MATH, 1]`. Or it could be just like `[CHEM, BIOL, MATH]`.

I tried this:

```
d.groupBy('auid').agg(func.collect_set(func.struct('city', 'year')).alias('city_set')).show(10, False)
```

which leads to this:

```
+----+--------------------------------+
|auid|city_set                        |
+----+--------------------------------+
|1234|[[Berlin, 2012], [London, 2010]]|
+----+--------------------------------+
```

Here I am stuck and need help. (would appreciate a hint on to sort values in `city_set`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregate of collect_list on `struct('year', 'city')`, sort the array and then use `transform` function to adjust the order of the fields. Similar to subjects, create an array of structs with two fields: `cnt` and `subject`, sort/desc the array of structs and then retrieve only `subject` field:

```
df_new = d.groupBy('auid').agg(
      func.sort_array(func.collect_set(func.struct('year', 'city'))).alias('city_set'),
      func.collect_list('subject').alias('subjects')
    ).withColumn('city_set', func.expr("transform(city_set, x -> (x.city as city, x.year as year))")) \
    .withColumn('subjects', func.expr("""
        sort_array(
          transform(array_distinct(subjects), x -> (size(filter(subjects, y -> y=x)) as cnt, x as subject)),
          False
        ).subject
      """))

df_new.show(truncate=False) 
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+
|auid|city_set                        |subjects          |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+
|1234|[[London, 2010], [Berlin, 2012]]|[CHEM, MATH, BIOL]|
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+
```

**Edit:** there are several ways to remove the duplicate city entries in `city_set` array:

1. use Window function to adjust `year` to min(year) for each city, and then repeat the above procedure.

   ```
   d = d.withColumn('year', func.min('year').over(Window.partitionBy('auid','city')))
   ```
2. use [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) function to remove duplicates from `city_set` array:

   ```
   df_new = d.groupBy('auid').agg(
       func.sort_array(func.collect_set(func.struct('year', 'city'))).alias('city_set')     
   ).withColumn("city_set", func.expr("""         
       aggregate(        
         /* expr: take slice of city_set array from the 2nd element to the last */
         slice(city_set,2,size(city_set)-1),           
         /* start: initialize `acc` as an array with a single entry city_set[0].city */
         array(city_set[0].city),
         /* merge: iterate through `expr`, if x.city exists in `acc`, keep as-is
          *        , otherwise add an entry to `acc` using concat function */
         (acc,x) -> IF(array_contains(acc,x.city), acc, concat(acc, array(x.city)))                     
       )                              
   """))
   ```

**Note:** it would be much easier with Spark 3.0+ though:

```
df_new = d.groupBy('auid').agg(func.expr("array_sort(collect_set((city,year)), (l,r) -> int(l.year-r.year)) as city_set"))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Can't figure yet, how to get a column with just cities, sorted chorolonogically, i.e. [London, Berlin]?

Comment: @ande , if you need just a single field from an array of structs, just skip the transform function and use the `dot` notation: `d.groupBy('auid').agg(func.sort_array(func.collect_set(func.struct('year', 'city'))).city.alias('city_set'))`, see also what we've done with the `subjects` column.

Comment: BTW. a more robust way is to use `.getItem('city')` or `['city']` in case the field name contains special chars like SPACE, dot etc.

Comment: again, thanks a lot! I do see some limitations of my example data, though. There can be two different documents affiliated with London, so in that case I see [London, London, Berlin], whereas I want to see [London, Berlin]. Is that possible you think?

Comment: @ande, you are very welcome. for the issue you just mentioned, I think a simple fix is to create a temporary column (or just overwrite the existing `year` column) using Window function, like: `d = d.withColumn('year_min', func.min('year').over(Window.partitionBy('auid','city')))`, then use year_min to replace year in the code.